# Minimalist Wiki like script

Tags: php, scripting, wiki

I'm trying to find a simple wiki like script to setup a personal directory, browser favorites simply doesn't do anymore and i have lots of small files on my flash drive

**Desired features**

- file upload
- not bloated
- works on a common webhost (aka php)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, it is not supported anymore apparently, but back in 2004 I had quite a good experience with this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwikiwiki/files/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org). Uses text files instead of a database.

Comment: Dokuwiki is one of the easiest solutions. We use it for our knowledgebase at work, works like a charm (and on the plus side you can take a copy of it with you on a USB stick because everything is stored in TXT files).

Comment: doku is a great wiki, but bloated for this kind of usage :/

Comment: @arthurprs What about this one? It probably doesn't accept file upload...it's  in Javascript: http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

Comment: I need to access it on the web :( ... I'm giving up on this

Comment: Docuwiki is installed on a PHP server! It IS on the web!

Answer (score 13):

[Google Sites](http://sites.google.com/) functions as a Wiki, and you don't have to make your site public.  You can upload files, but there's a 100MB limit for a site.  The big advantage here (IMO) is the fact that you don't have to worry about setting up hosting at all.

It has a WYSIWYG editor, so that's a minus if you're really into some particular Wiki syntax, I guess.

Another (non-hosted) option would be [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/), which is completely implemented in Javascript and meant to be used on a USB drive, primarily.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of people have recommended [Tiddlywiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/). I've used it for a simple wiki setup... It's nice, fast, and easy.

You mentioned the need for web-access... Tiddlywiki combined with [TiddlyHome](http://www.hornord.net/tw/) is what I use for a simple, single-html-page wiki, which can be used both offline and online...

Another possibility is to use one of the new saving options listed at https://tiddlywiki.com/#Saving, including a Node.js or PHP server, or Google Drive/Dropbox/WebDAV (Sharepoint) integration.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could help you find one that suits your needs: http://www.wikimatrix.org/

I found also this nice script: [Hatta](http://hatta.sheep.art.pl/)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout LionWiki - http://lionwiki.0o.cz

It works from just one file and it's dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one:

```
<?php function p($c){$r=preg_replace(array("~^ +([^\n]+)~m",'~^-\s+(.*)$~m',
"~-{4,}\r?\n~",'~(http(?:s)?)://([^\s]+)~i','~\n~'),array('<code>$1</code>','<li>$1',
'<hr>','<a href=$1://$2>$2</a>','<br>'),$c);preg_match_all('~([A-Z]\w+){2,}~',$r,
$x);foreach(array_unique($x[0])as$m){$r=str_replace($m,x($m)? "<a href=?$m>$m</a>":
"$m<a href=?e=$m>?</a>",$r);}return$r;}function f($f){@mkdir('wik');return
@file_get_contents("wik/$f.w");}function b($b){echo"<h1><a href=?$b>Backlinks $b"
."</a></h1><div id=c>";foreach(glob('wik/*.w')as$f){$f=substr($f,4,-2);if(strpos(
f($f),$b)!==false)echo"<a href=?$f>$f</a><br>";}echo"</div>";}function x($f){
return file_exists("wik/$f.w");}function e($p){$p=$p?$p:$_GET['e'];echo"<h1>Edit"
." $p</h1><form action='?$p' method=post><textarea name=c cols=50 rows=10>".f($p)
."</textarea><br><input type=submit value=Save>";}$p=preg_replace('~(e|b)=(.*)~'
,'',$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]);$c=$_POST[c];$e=$_GET[e];$b=$_GET[b];if(!$p&&!$e)$p=
'MainPage';if($c){@file_put_contents("wik/$p.w",htmlspecialchars($c));header(
"Location: ?$p");}echo"<title>Wik Wiki</title>";if(!$e){if(!$b){echo x($p)?
"<h1><a href=?b=$p>$p</a></h1><div id=c>".p(f($p))."</div><hr><a href=?e=$p>"
."Edit</a> | <small>Modified: ".date('d.m.Y @ H:i:s', @filemtime("wik/$p.w"))
:e($p);}else b($b);}else e($e);
```

It's from http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WikWiki. It doesn't have file upload but you should be able to add it without bloating. I've used it as a private notepad and it works well, you just have to make sure the web server has write permissions on the wik directory